# How can I access the variable "verify" from following instance?

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6, omnipay

I have the response of instance I wanted to access the specific variable

I tried different combinations, using the arrow operator.

```
Client {#445 ▼
  -httpClient: Client {#460 ▼
   -client: Client {#469 ▼
   -config: array:7 [▼
    "handler" => HandlerStack {#459 ▶}
    "allow_redirects" => array:5 [▶]
    "http_errors" => true
    "decode_content" => true
    "verify" => true
    "cookies" => false
    "headers" => array:1 [▼
      "User-Agent" => "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.50.1 PHP/7.0.10"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to access the array variables like handler, verify and cookies.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, so we can help you help yourself.

Comment: I tried 
    var_dump($this->httpClient);
        var_dump($this->httpClient->getConfig());

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the config from Guzzle Client using '$client->getConfig()' call (if `$client` is your `\GuzzleHttp\Client` instance).

Look at the code here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.3.3/src/Client.php#L134